# How to render two different meshlets at two different LODs in a Mesh Shader?

Tags: c++, rendering, glsl, 3d-meshes, level-of-detail

I would like to know how to render two different meshlet at two different LOD values.

So, for example, I render the meshletA at LOD1 and I render the mesheletB at LOD2.

Please let me know if this is possible, and if so, how to set it up.